# How to use properly the PostgreSQL operator ?| to select data from a table conains a column with a text[]

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my table Documents I have to retrieve the document ID where I have the recipientIds

The PSQL I was trying but with error `operator does not exist: text[] ?| unknown`

```
select
    *
from
    documents d
where
    recipients::text[] ?| array['qfxKzhSc5tsaZ4ko6AxMb',
    'Y9RKXWGXnD2J_5bxyfNRN']::text[]
```

The table document looks as this

[image: Document table]

As you see the recipients column is where I have the issue as that data type is

```
'{}'::text[]
```

My result should that given an array of recipientIds like `['qfxKzhSc5tsaZ4ko6AxMb','Y9RKXWGXnD2J_5bxyfNRN']`
I'm selecting the corresponding documents.id.

I tried to us the `@>` but this contains operator match only what we have in the array but not if I put two different recipientIds as like above in my example.

I need to use the `OR` operator and I thought this `?|` will do the trick but I have error and don't know the proper way of doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `&&` operator:

```
SELECT * 
FROM documents d
WHERE recipients && array['qfxKzhSc5tsaZ4ko6AxMb','Y9RKXWGXnD2J_5bxyfNRN'];
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=eb9048f816be688f5cc5845ecd65ebc4)

```
CREATE TABLE documents (recipients text[]);
INSERT INTO documents 
VALUES (array['qfxKzhSc5tsaZ4ko6AxMb','Y9RKXWGXnD2J_5bxyfNRN']);
```

Complete overlap

```
SELECT * FROM documents d
WHERE recipients && array['qfxKzhSc5tsaZ4ko6AxMb','Y9RKXWGXnD2J_5bxyfNRN'];

                  recipients                   
-----------------------------------------------
 {qfxKzhSc5tsaZ4ko6AxMb,Y9RKXWGXnD2J_5bxyfNRN}
```

Partial overlap

```
SELECT * FROM documents d
WHERE recipients && array['foo','Y9RKXWGXnD2J_5bxyfNRN'];

                  recipients                   
-----------------------------------------------
 {qfxKzhSc5tsaZ4ko6AxMb,Y9RKXWGXnD2J_5bxyfNRN}
```

No overlap

```
SELECT * FROM documents d
WHERE recipients && array['foo','bar'];

 recipients 
------------
(0 rows)
```